# Regarding space launch hazard and near earth debris

Tags: space-mission, solar-system-exploration

I have saw this picture in wikipedia

[image]

and I begin to wonder why doesn't current space launches take consideration of avoiding space debris, as say you want to sent a robotic mission to mars, during the launching phase do you have to calculate your trajectory to avoid colliding your spaceship with near earth debris, or is this collision not a concerning issue, in addition why don't scientist seems to be worry about deep space collision with small rocks, it seems to me that if a spaceship travels to mars there seems to be a significant probability of colliding with small rocks?

Comment: Have you asked how many objects are *not* being tracked yet?

Comment: What makes you think they don't worry about it?  There is a lot of money spent tracking space junk because it causes a lot of catastrophic problems.

Comment: @dmckee according to wikipedia, currently there is around 19000 debris larger than 5 cm and 300000 debris smaller than 1cm, but what confuses me is that given so much debris it seems to be impossible to manuever the spacecraft and avoid collision

Comment: @user6972, when I was looking at the launch history of mar probe, non of them seems to mention the difficulty of launching due to near earth debris

Comment: I think the spacecraft's fuselage has enough strength so that these small debris are not much of a problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it better goes to [space exploration](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/43283/space-exploration)

Comment: @Dilaton Perhaps it would be better there, but that logic is not sound. Whether or not a question belongs here is a judgement made independently of whether or not it would be even better off elsewhere.

Comment: @ChrisWhite hm, David asked in chat if it is off topic and I thought the physics content is a bit weak, which would maybe less matter on space exploration (?)...

Answer (score 2):

There are many considerations here of the engineering sort that would be more appropriate for [Space Exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com). That said, the *most important* thing to note is that pictures like that are **extremely misleading**.

Placing a dot for each piece of known debris is all well and good, except your mind doesn't count dots (you can barely count beyond three just by glancing at something - try it). Instead, you look at the relative areas being filled - white "problems areas" on a black "this area is okay" zone. But those dots are *not to scale*. The space debris would be microscopic on this scale. Furthermore, this is a 2D projection of a 3D scenario - there is a lot more room to maneuver than it appears. Essentially this picture would be accurate only if each piece of debris was a long cylinder hundreds of kilometers in diameter and tens of thousands of kilometers long. Only then would the situation be quite so dire.

To plug in some numbers: That ring of stuff is in [geostationary orbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit) around Earth, which is at a radius of $42{,}000\ \mathrm{km}$.<sup>1</sup> The volume around Earth going out that far is then $3\times10^{23}\ \mathrm{m}^3$. Suppose your rocket has a $10\ \mathrm{m}^2$ cross section and will travel a path length of $100{,}000\ \mathrm{km}$ through this zone, and suppose there are $100{,}000$ pieces of worrisome debris. If everything were uniformly distributed, the odds of running into even one piece are still something like $1$ in $3$ billion.

The situation is a bit worse restricted to low-Earth orbit, and indeed spacecraft are sometimes maneuvered to avoid known objects, but really the same principle applies. There are concerns that might cause you to make small adjustments, but it's not like you'd be dodging raindrops in a thunderstorm, as that image depicts.

This is also the same principle behind the reason you could fly through the Asteroid Belt or the Oort Cloud without worry. Yes there are lots of objects, but space is **really, really** vast.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note you will often see the figure of $36{,}000\ \mathrm{km}$, but this is altitude above Earth's surface.

Comment: The size of the debris isn't as important as its momentum relative to the craft.  Thus all those dots are important, not just the larger ones, even if the graphic isn't to scale.  Also I doubt that there is much debris that is geosynchronous as their orbits are typically not stable.  Space is vast but I don't think the odds are that good in orbit.  Even tiny paint chips have ripped holes in the shuttle. Good overview: http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5050/projects/projects_2003/wilson/

Answer (score 1):

Debris is a big problem.  According to the EU report:

> Economic losses for European satellite operators stemming from
>   collisions or costly and risky manoeuvres to avoid collisions are
>   currently assessed at around €140 million per year, rising to about
>   €210 million per year within the next decade. The economic loss on the
>   ground due to the disruption of applications or services that rely on
>   data from satellites lost or damaged cannot be quantified, but implies
>   a significantly higher figure.
>
> It is estimated that up to 600,000 objects larger than 1 cm orbit the
>   Earth, and at least 16,000 larger than 10 cm. An object larger than 1
>   cm hitting a satellite will damage or destroy sub-systems or
>   instruments on board, and a collision with an object larger than 10 cm
>   will destroy the satellite. Space debris also poses a risk to
>   ground-based infrastructures and citizens' security when it falls out
>   of orbit and re-enters the Earth's atmosphere.

Launches are constantly timed to allow a window where there is low risk of hitting debris.  The fact the the mars probe launch history doesn't comment on it doesn't mean they haven't spent a lot of time making sure they had a clean window to avoid costly delays like these:

> "The launch of PSLV-C18 carrying four satellites including
>   Megha-Tropiques from Sriharikota was delayed by a minute after a
>   warning by an agency about possible collision with space debris."
>
> "The launch of a rocket carrying a secret payload has been postponed
>   for two weeks to avoid possible space debris from the destruction of a
>   spy satellite..."

The ISS has had emergency alerts causing the crew to camp in the evacuation module until the threat had passed:

> The three crew members on board the International Space Station were
>   told to “evacuate” into the Soyuz spacecraft earlier today, when they
>   were notified of possible debris hit to the station.

Read more: http://www.universetoday.com/26958/close-call-astronauts-evacuate-but-space-station-avoids-debris-hit/#ixzz2b2Jjz2Ln

There are many sites around the world tracking debris and analyzing collision risks:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Orbital_Debris_Observatory
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Strategic_Command
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESA_Space_Debris_Telescope
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_Deep_Space_Communications_Complex
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haystack_Observatory

NASA has written a [detailed report](http://en.wikinews.org/wiki/Out_of_space_in_outer_space%3a_Special_report_on_NASA%27s_%27space_junk%27_plans) of the issue as well.